# Overall download time calculation with max connection cap

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

Can somebody point to me to the algorithm for calculating download estimate with maximum connection caps. For instance I have 7 PCs with different download speed and I can have only X devices allowed to download at once.

```
Speed(Kbps) Size(Kb)    Estimate(s)
10          1000        100
50          1000        20
100         1000        10
200         1000        5
10          1000        100
20          1000        50
40          1000        25
```

*Estimate = Size/Speed

What comes in mind is `Sum(Estimate)/MaxConnections` but it seems inaccurate.

If X=2 then result using that logic will be 310/2=155 but in real life it will be 160:

```
1st iteration:
1 thread: 100s
2 thread: 100s
```

Total Elapsed: 100s

```
2nd iteration:
1 thread: 50s
2 thread: 25s + 20s + 5s
```

Total Elapsed: 150s

```
3rd iteration:
1 thread: 10s
```

Total Elapsed: 160s

Comment: Why the optimal is not 155 with thread1={100,50,5},thread2={100,25,20,10}?

Comment: @amit true, not perfect example I have chosen, but it is just a special case for instance with same data but with X=3 you will get thread1={100}, thread2={100}, thread3={50,25,20,5} and in 2nd iteration will left thread1=10 so in total it is 110s when using that logic it comes 310/3=103.3(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a variation of [k-partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_k-partition_problem), where you want to 'split' the work as evenly as possible between the X devices you have. Unfortunately, this problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), and **there is no known efficient solution to it**.

When X=2, and estimations are relatively small integers, there is a [pseudo-polynomial solution to the problem using Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_algorithm).

However, for general X, the problem there is no known pseudo polynomial solution.

What you can do:

- Using  heuristics solutions such as [Genetic Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) to split the
  work in groups. These solution will usually be pretty good - but not optimal.
- Use brute force approach to find optimal solution. Note it will only be feasible for very low number of items you want to download, and specifically it is going to be `O(X^n)`, with `n` being the number of elements you download.

Comment: Thanks @amit I was missing that terminology.